# How to run play project in dev mode with Typesafe Activator UI

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I am using Typesafe Activator 1.2.10. I created a new project with activator ui from template play-scala.

When I click Start, play is running in prod mode. I would like to run it in dev mode. How to do that with activator ui?

See below logs after un click Start.

[image: console ouptput after click on run]

PS: I know how to run this project in dev mode from command line with activator with command : activator run

Edit: 
My issue is probably what has been reported here https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/601

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with plugins and play-scala seed:

just change project/plugins.sbt to this

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Cloudbees
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snasphots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.0-RC2")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0-RC2")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0-RC3")
```

and recompile project. App is running in dev mode and auto-recompile on refresh is working!

https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/601#issuecomment-72938901